# using JavasSript to check checkboxes in PHP form

Tags: php, javascript, forms

Hi I am trying to add some function which only allows the user to select up to 4 checkboxes at a time, but failing miserably... php and javascript don't seem to be working together very well!

my PHP code is:

```
<?php
echo "<form method='post' name='time' action='timeinsert.php'>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' `name='$displayTime2'onclick='KeepCount()'></td>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

my Javascript code is:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--`
function KeepCount() {
var NewCount = 0
if (document.time.<?php"$displayTime2"?>.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1}
f (NewCount == 4)
{
alert("Pick maximum of 4 time slot's Please")
document.time; return false;`
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: declare "var NewCount = 0" globally. i.e., above the function keepCount(), coz every time you check the checkbox it will be assigned to 0.

Comment: Write echo here `if (document.time.<?php echo $displayTime2 ?>.checked)`
I also suggest that you use document.getElementsByName('input') and loop through them instead of a counter. With jQuery it's even simpler..

Comment: I've tried both of these methods but still not getting anywhere, I'm just looking into jQuery but I'm new to both languages, could somebody please post an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
            var count = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;   
            if (count > 4) alert('Pick maximum of 4 time slots please!');
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
    echo "<form method='post' name='time' action='timeinsert.php'>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='$displayTime2'></td>";
    echo "</form>";
?>
```

UPDATE:  To prevent further checks from happening after 4 clicks, you can do this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
            var count = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;   
            if (count > 4) {
                $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                alert('Pick maximum of 4 time slots please!');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you Stefan that worked well in terms of getting a popup, but users are still able to select more boxes after the popup... I have tried amending the code to: 
'$(function() { var theCheckboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"); theCheckboxes.click(function () { var count = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length; if (theCheckboxes.filter(":checked").length > 3) alert('Pick maximum of 4 time slots please!').$(this).removeAttr("checked");  }); });'

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">    

    var NewCount = 0;

    function KeepCount() 
    {
      if(NewCount <= 4)
      {
          if (document.time.<?php echo $displayTime2; ?>.checked)
          { 
               NewCount = parseInt(NewCount)+1;
          }
      }
      else
      {
         alert("Pick maximum of 4 time slot's Please");   
         return false;  
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: not sure why this didn't work, I think it may have something to do with dropping in to php here:

 if (document.time.<?php echo $displayTime2; ?>.checked)

".checked" comes up red in Notepad++ so that indicates it's an error

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have now edited Stefan's code and come up with:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='includes/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
            var count = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;   
            if (count > 4) alert('Pick maximum of 4 time slots please!');
        if (count > 4) $(this).removeAttr("checked");
        });
    });
</script>
```

this alerts the user and removes and ticks after 4 checkboxes have already been selected. Is it possible to add 
    $(this).removeAttr("checked");
to the first if statement rather than adding another line of code?

Comment: It's possible to use one `if` statement only, but you still need the additional statement to uncheck the box when the count is larger than 4 - see the update to my answer.